# Catch exception while initializing static final variable

Tags: java, exception, static, final

I have following code:

```
public class LoadProperty
{
public static final String property_file_location = System.getProperty("app.vmargs.propertyfile");
public static final String application-startup_mode = System.getProperty("app.vmargs.startupmode");
}
```

It reads from 'VM arguments' and assigns to variables.

Since static final variable is only initialized at class load, 
how can I catch exception in case some one forgets to pass parameter.

As of now, when I am using 'property_file_location' variable, exception is encountered in following cases:

- If value is present, and location is wrong, FileNotFound exception comes.
- If it is not initialized properly(value is null), it throws NullPointerException.

I need to handle second case at time of initialization only.

Similiar is case of second variable.

Whole idea is

- To initialize application configuration parameters.
- If successfully initialized, continue.
- If not, alert user and terminate application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static initializer block as suggested by the rest of the answers. Even better move this functionality to a static utility class so you can still use them as an one-liner. You could then even provide default values e.g.

```
// PropertyUtils is a new class that you implement
// DEFAULT_FILE_LOCATION could e.g. out.log in current folder
public static final String property_file_location = PropertyUtils.getProperty("app.vmargs.propertyfile", DEFAULT_FILE_LOCATION);
```

However if those properties are not expected to exist all the time, I would suggest to not initialize them as static variables but read them during normal execution.

```
// in the place where you will first need the file location
String fileLocation = PropertyUtils.getProperty("app.vmargs.propertyfile");
if (fileLocation == null) {
    // handle the error here
}
```

Comment: Above parameters were subset of actual. 
I have parameters which I am using all the time. 
This aproach should work for me. 
PropertyUtils.getProperty(), will give me way to do exception handling. 
I will try.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch it this way:

```
public class LoadProperty
{
    public static final String property_file_location;

    static {
        String myTempValue = MY_DEFAULT_VALUE;
        try {
            myTempValue = System.getProperty("app.vmargs.propertyfile");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            myTempValue = MY_DEFAULT_VALUE;
        }
        property_file_location = myTempValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last asignation `property_file_location = myTempValue;`must be inside a finally block

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a static bloc :

```
public static final property_file_location;
static {
  try {
    property_file_location = System.getProperty("app.vmargs.propertyfile");
  } catch (xxx){//...}
}
```

Comment: That's because if it fails your final variable isn't set. so you could add a `finally {proeprty_file_location = null};`

Comment: Even with a finally clause, have a try and compile it.